# Dynamic extension if class in java

Tags: java, oop

I have classes as below, code in  com.message.java(Child.java) is ported code from scala.
What i am trying  to do is extended either com.message.java or com.message.scala code to com.message.wrapper(Child.java)  at runtime,  so com.message.wrapper will act as a wrapper. So i can switch between the code if there is any issue in my ported code. These both java and scala are in different jars. Is is possible in java.

com.message.java
Child.java

com.message.scala
Child.scala

com.message.wrapper
Child.java

Comment: Can you give a bit more of (pseudo) code? But in general: java is statically typed. There is no "dynamic" switching of parent classes, as (in byte code) classes are ALWAYS referred to with their absolute name.

Comment: In other words: the proper OO approach would be that either your wrapper class knows to wrap around BOTH kind of parent classes, or that well, use some sort of interface.

Comment: Interface i can use in my ported code, but not possible to change the existing jar with scala code.

Comment: Then your wrapper needs to written in a way that it can deal with EITHER of two classes, but you wont be able to dynamically inherit classes.